# Refresh Google Visualization on the fly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-visualization

I am currently creating a google chart via google visualization and I want to be able to refresh/update this chart on a button click.  I've tried a lot of different ways to do this but none of it works so I'm looking for any suggestions that anybody can make.  My current platform is ASP.net (with C#) and the google stuff is written in javascript/jquery (obviously).  Thanks!

Comment: You want to update without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: How about an updatepanel then?

Comment: Tried it, the visualization disappears after the partial postback despite the code for it being there.  It seems as though google's setOnLoadCallback never calls back and if I call that function directly, it simply disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gviz has the option to populate charts with JSON data, so, you can do this with jquery easily enough simply by making a call to your server to get a new set of data, having it return JSON, then passing this to a function that draws your charts.

Your jquery/javascript wil look something like this:

```
    function drawMyChart(data) {
        // stuff to draw chart using the contents of data
        // data should be Gviz Data Table in JSON format
        // your server needs to output this
        var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(data)
        // rest of your stuff, just like standard gviz
    }

    function makeAjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/data/json',
            sucess: drawMyChart(a),
            dataType: 'json' // this is important, have it interpreted as json
        });
    }
// html somewhere
<input type='button' onclick='makeAjaxCall()'>Go</input>
```

With regard to correctly formatting your JSON response, there are a couple of libraries out there to help you, though I don't know of anything specifically in the languages you mentioned. Here's one in [python](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-python/) for example.

If you're struggling, you can just dump out all of your entries in an array as follows:

```
  [[name, age],[john, 25],[paul, 20]]
```

and use [google.visualization.arrayToDataTable](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#google.visualization.arraytodatatable) to interpret it when it arrives back from your server as JSON.

Hope that helps.